# Sidekiq not sending mails even it shows processed in sidekiq ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq with rails 4.1.8. it's working good in local/development environment, but not sending mails in production.i am using redis-server 2.8.4 and doing bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml.                                                                                                             The whole process working in development but in production it is not sending mails.  Thank you.